# How to reload page after a modal does not contain a particular className using Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a modal with `id="modal-1"` that contains the class `modal-visible` after a successful fetch api `post`. How do you reload the page if that `modal-1` does not have `modal-visible` (essentially after the user closes the modal)?

Is this correct?

```
if (document.querySelector("#modal-1").classList.contains("modal-visible")) {} else {
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: what is the problem here?

Comment: @SamuelG is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: seems fine, you can simplify slightly and add an undefined guard -- I added a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing seems correct, you can simplify and add an undefined guard as follows:

```js
if (document.querySelector("#modal-1") && !document.querySelector("#modal-1").classList.contains("modal-visible")) {
  console.info('reloading...');
  //  window.location.reload();
};
```

```html
<div id="modal-1" class=""></div>
```